# Can I charge my HP laptop through USB if I plug the other end into the wall?

Tags: windows-7, usb, hp-pavilion, charging

I have a Pavilion dv7 by HP, 11.1v battery. The battery will not hold a charge and my charger was stolen. I cannot afford a new one at the moment. How else can I charge it?

Comment: No, you can't, and you may cause damage if you try. The only answer is a new charger: you may be able to find a compatible one, though there is a risk with it, and I wouldn't think it worth the saving.

Comment: USB ports are not constructed for charging the laptop.

Comment: I'm not allowed to make recommendations​ for specific products, but a little searching on Amazon will yield a standard 65w charger with a good rating under $15 delivered.

Answer (score 2):

Laptops (or at least this certain model) are not charged via USB. Laptops have fundamental differences from phones.

Comment: Although you are correct, I do not find the answer satisfying enough with knowledge to give you a +1 vote.

Comment: @LPChip LOL. I don't think I deserve it either, but if you don't, in the future, "Community" will pester everyone by bumping it to the top once in a while. Let's face it: Dumb question cannot possibly get Einstein-class answers.

Comment: LOL +1 on your answer for that reply! :) good one.